# carto.com when 2 points have the same location

Tags: postgis, postgresql, carto, sql

Carto.com: We are mapping homicides and when two deaths occur at the same location, how do I prevent 2 points with the same lat, lon from overwriting each other?  I want to be able to view each point and the associated data.

Comment: Using a SQL query to detect the points that are equal and moving one slightly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several alternatives using CARTO to solve the points-overlapping problem. First, if you have a timestamp column and the deaths have happened in two different dates, [you can use Torque](https://carto.com/torque/). That is an animated map. Second, the Wizard of the old Editor allow you to aggregate points [in clusters, intensity or density maps](https://carto.com/academy/courses/beginners-course/thematic-maps-with-point-data/).

But my favorite example is using [the *stacking chip* method](https://carto.com/blog/stacking-chips-a-map-hack/) (sorry for the old blog post). This is basically a hack using PostGIS functions:

```
WITH 
  m AS (
    SELECT array_agg(cartodb_id) id_list, the_geom_webmercator, ST_Y(the_geom_webmercator) y 
    FROM table_name
    GROUP BY the_geom_webmercator 
    ORDER BY y DESC
  ),
  f AS (
    SELECT  generate_series(1, array_length(id_list,1)) p, unnest(id_list) cartodb_id, the_geom_webmercator 
    FROM m
  )
SELECT  ST_Translate(f.the_geom_webmercator,0,f.p*50) the_geom_webmercator, f.cartodb_id, q.city, q.country
FROM f, table_name q
WHERE f.cartodb_id = q.cartodb_id
```

[Here](http://bl.ocks.org/ramiroaznar/1e45bdd58994aee8293d) you can find a working example using CARTO.js.

Comment: That's a very cool approach.

Comment: Excellent, that is exactly what we needed.  Cool approach indeed.