# How to style markers so they dynamically offset if overlapping at different zoom levels?

Tags: carto, markers, html, cartocss, icon

> *I have created a map using Carto. The map has bespoke images as icon markers. I would like to style the map so that, if the icons overlap,
>   they both render in an offset position so that the full icons are
>   visible, perhaps with a line to the actual co-ordinates. Ideally a
>   function for this exists and can handle any overlap dynamically, if
>   not some manual tips on offset styling will help.*
>
> *An example of the issue I have is here: https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/custom-marker-icons/ If
>   you zoom out far enough on the map, the icons will begin to overlap,
>   which is the behavior I wish to prevent.*
>
> *Clustering is not an option as I have unique images that need to be visible.*
>
> *Spidering/Spiderfy (http://jawj.github.io/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier-Leaflet/demo.html)
>   looks close to what I am after, but this only splits the icons on
>   click rather than as standard.*

Moving on from the original question above, i have managed to create hard-coded offsets for overlapping features with the below sql:

```
    SELECT cartodb_id, tree, capacity, the_geom_webmercator FROM tablea  where tree NOT IN ('Oak','Willow')
UNION SELECT cartodb_id, tree, capacity, st_translate(the_geom_webmercator,20000,0) as the_geom_webmercator FROM tablea where tree = 'Oak'
UNION SELECT cartodb_id, tree, capacity, st_translate(the_geom_webmercator,10000,10000) as the_geom_webmercator FROM tablea where tree = 'Willow'
```

This brings in all other elements in tablea and then styles specific elements with an offset on the X,Y bringing them all together as a union select.

Unfortunately this creates a problem. The hard coded offset is fine at certain zoom levels but looks odd in others. Ideally I want a zoom specific sql query. From what I can tell this doesn't exist in Carto, and you can only style the CSS at specific zoom levels?

Mapbox have created a postGIS function that runs the below:

```
( SELECT * FROM roads
  WHERE Z(!scale_denominator!) >= 12
) AS data
```

Does anyone know of the Carto equivalent to this? Or perhaps advice on an alternative method?

Comment: This is a duplicated, [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/203095/carto-com-when-2-points-have-the-same-location/) you can find a similar Q/A.

Comment: Thanks @ramiroaznar. It seems the solution in the link provided is for the stacked marker solution, which isn't appropriate for the icons I have. i am surprised a function to offset icons when their bbox clashes with another icon doesn't exist. If someone could summarise the functions out there for overlapping markers, I could move on to adjusting things manually if need be.

Comment: If clustering, spidifying or stacking do not work for you. You have to make a taylor/custom solution such as styling your layer depending on zoom using CartoCSS offset properties or duplicating the layer, and playing with `the_geom` and hinding/showing layers depending on the zoom.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [carto.com when 2 points have the same location](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/203095/carto-com-when-2-points-have-the-same-location)

Comment: Afraid not. My points do not sit at the same x,y but they overlap at certain zoom levels. I am after a zoom specific query that can use translate to adjust the x or y (or both) if markers overlap.